# How to show alert in Javascript from controller to view with span

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I found a error in my script.

I want to call alert javascript and show up in my view with span text. But with my script its nothing happen. The span not showing from alert on controller.

This is my controller :

```
public function validate_objectb()
{
    $id_with = $_POST['id'];
    $objectb= $_POST['objectb'];

    $data = array(
        'id' => $id_with,
        'objectb' => $objectb
    );
    $objecta = $this->session->userdata('objecta');

    if ($objecta != $objectb)
    {
        echo '<script>var error = document.getElementById("message-validate")
            error.innerHTML = "<span style=color: red;>"+ 
                    "Your object didnt same with partial.</span>" 
            </script>';
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('box',$data);
    }
```

This is my view **[UPDATE]**:

```
<?php echo form_open('controllers/validate','class="form"');?>
<select name="objectb" id="objectb" class="form-control">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="check">Check Object</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add Again</button>
<span id="message-validate" class="message-form"></span>
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

In my case I want user if first time pick `objecta` and `objecta` save session with `set_userdata` and for check data. If didn't same with `objectb` the validate message showing in view page, and if same the `objecta` & `objectb` save to `database`.

And with my script nothing happened

Comment: Are you submitting the form using javascript and Ajax?

Comment: No, i just using javascript in my controller to get the alert

Comment: If you submit the form "normally" without ajax, then the page should reload, and from what I can see in the posted controller, you don't return the rest of the HTML? This should just generate a blank page? Or are you returning the complete page in the rest of the code we can't see?

Comment: Before i just use the this script, i use `//echo "<script>alert('Your object didnt same with partial')</script>;";` . And normally the alert showing but i want to use span and not alert box

Answer (score 0):

You're using ...

```
document.getElementById("message-validate")
```

... but "message-validate" is the element's class, not it's ID:

```
<span class="message-form message-validate"></span>
```

You should either set "message-validate" as the span's ID:

```
<span id="message-validate" class="message-form"></span>
```

or get the element by it's class.:

```
var error = document.getElementsByClassName("message-validate")
```

Keep in mind that if you decide to select the element by it's class, then all "message-validate" classed elements will spawn the error message in your page.

EDIT

I would try to echo the script separately:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"
echo "var error = document.getElementById('message-validate')"
echo "error.innerHTML = 'Error message';"
echo "</script>"
```

Comment: @IvanBahri try debugging on your preferred browser. Also, try echoing your script separately as I edited in the answer.